# Type equality in the Scala 2.10 Reflection API

Tags: scala, reflection, types, scala-2.10

I'm running into a weird issue with reflection in [Scala 2.10.0 Milestone 4](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/12702) that I can't wrap my head around. First for the stuff that works the way I'd expect:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> trait A[X]; trait B[Y] extends A[Y]
defined trait A
defined trait B

scala> typeOf[B[String]].parents
res0: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(java.lang.Object, A[String])

scala> typeOf[B[String]].parents contains typeOf[A[String]]
res1: Boolean = true
```

Similarly (in the same session):

```
scala> trait D; trait E extends A[D]
defined trait D
defined trait E

scala> typeOf[E].parents
res2: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(java.lang.Object, A[D])

scala> typeOf[E].parents contains typeOf[A[D]]
res3: Boolean = true
```

No surprises here: I can ask for a type's parents and get exactly what I expect. Now I essentially combine the two examples above:

```
scala> trait F extends A[String]
defined trait F

scala> typeOf[F].parents
res4: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(java.lang.Object, A[String])

scala> typeOf[F].parents contains typeOf[A[String]]
res5: Boolean = false
```

I don't understand how this could be false. The same thing happens if I have `F` extend `A[Seq[D]]`, `A[Int]`, etc. What's the generalization I'm missing that would make this behavior make sense?

Comment: I just confirmed that this is fixed in 2.10.0-M5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a bug. Right this morning I was going to investigate and fix it.

**Edit**. this appears to be an implementation detail of Scala reflection API leaking to the userland. It's not easy to fix, so for now we leave it as it is, but will look into the possibilities to improve.

In the meanwhile, to get correct results, one should always use `=:=` to compare types, not `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Another illustration of the strangeness:

```
scala> val atype = typeOf[A[String]]
atype: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = A[String]

scala> val atype2 = typeOf[F].parents(1)
atype2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = A[String]

scala> typeOf[F].parents contains atype
res39: Boolean = false

scala> typeOf[F].parents contains atype2
res40: Boolean = true
```

I think you're seeing a bug similar to this one:  https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5959 (although I've confirmed that this oddness occurs outside of the REPL too).

Comment: Right, this also happens outside REPL. Thanks for the report!

Comment: An update. This is actually caused by incorrect behaviour of typeOf: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6005.