# Is there a way to create transform two equivalent types in Scala reflection into two equal types?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Consider the following:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[Boolean]
res23: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Boolean

scala> typeOf[scala.Boolean]
res24: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Boolean

scala> res23 == res24
res25: Boolean = true

scala> typeOf[java.lang.Boolean]
res26: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Boolean

scala> res23 == res26
res27: Boolean = false

scala> class Foo { def bf(arg: Boolean) = ??? }
defined class Foo

scala> typeOf[Foo]
res28: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Foo

scala> res28.member(newTermName("bf")).asMethod
res30: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = method bf

scala> res30.paramss.head.head
res31: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = value arg

scala> res31.typeSignature
res32: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.Boolean

scala> res32 == res23
res33: Boolean = false

scala> res32 =:= res23
res37: Boolean = true
```

So the type obtained via the typeOf[Boolean] function is equivalent to the type obtained via inspecting a method, but it is not equal.

Is there a way to transform two equivalent types into some canonical representation where the results will be equal?  I'd like to be able to use them for things like keys in maps.

### Edit:

To be more clear, what I'm looking for is something along the lines of (not a real repl session):

```
scala>val tp1 = // some type
scala>val tp2 = // equivalent type obtained another way
scala>tp1 == tp2
res1: Boolean = false
scala>tp1 =:= tp2
res2: Boolean = true
scala>val ctp1 = tp1.canonical
scala>val ctp2 = tp2.canonical
scala>ctp1 == ctp2
res3: Boolean = true
scala>ctp1 =:= tp1
res4: Boolean = true
scala>ctp2 =:= tp2
res5: Boolean = true
```

So equivalence is preserved by the transformation. I also need it to work on parameterized types.

Comment: I do not fancy trying to turn the elaborate hierarchy of `isSameType` machinations into a `hashCode`.  So I would say _in general probably not_.

Comment: I don't see an easy way here either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types):

> It's important to note that `==` should not be used to compare types for
>   equality—`==` can't check for type equality in the presence of type
>   aliases, while `=:=` can.

You can of course store the types in a list and use (for example) the following to check for inclusion:

```
myTypes.exists(_ =:= someType)
```

You'll see this approach in the 2.10 compiler source, for example. It's not as efficient as a map or set, of course, but you generally don't have many of these things in a collection.

If you absolutely have to have the performance of a map or set, you may be able to use `erasure` (as another answer suggests) or `typeSymbol`, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware.  Please see the edits I just made to my question for more clarity.  Should I interpret your answer as what I'm looking for does not exist?

Comment: Well, there's definitely nothing exactly like what you want, and given what I know, I'd guess that writing e.g. a wrapper implementing a `hashCode` that would be consistent with `=:=` would be a huge headache. But I'm still learning new things about 2.10 every day, so you may not want to take that as 100% authoritative.

Comment: I think it doesn't exist.  If someone comes along with a "but here it is!" I'll select their answer.

Comment: Sounds fair to me. You may want to send up a flare for [Eugene Burmako](https://twitter.com/xeno_by)—he often weighs in on questions like this (see for example [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11258836/334519) to [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11254893/334519) I had a few months ago).

Answer (score 2):

`erasure` method of `scala.reflect.api.Types.TypeApi`:

```
typeOf[Foo].member(newTermName("bf")).asMethod.paramss.head.head
  .typeSignature.erasure == typeOf[Boolean]
// res21: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Clever, but it won't work for parameterized type because it erases the type parameters.  The result is that the results of tpe.erasure is not equivalent to tpe if tpe had non-Any type parameters.  Furthermore, if  you have, say, Option[Int] and Option[String] after erasure they will be equivalent.  So this doesn't work in the general case.